# namebench says hosts are being hijacked by my DNS - is this for real?

Tags: networking, dns, man-in-the-middle, hijack

I've been experiencing strange and annoying latency issues with my connection, despite the bandwidth seeming ok - especially latency with name resolution. So, I just ran [Google namebench](https://code.google.com/archive/p/namebench/). So, it gave me puzzling [results](http://tx.technion.ac.il/~eyalroz/content/namebench_2016-03-17_2226.html), in which the unexpected surprise is the claim (?) that hosts are being HIJACKED.

Is that for real? Where could this attack be made from? I'm running Linux here, so I don't expect this is a virus or trojan... could it be my router? my provider? elsewhere? And how can I verify/debunk this suspicion?

(help!)

Comment: sorry, I don't visit strange links, but does it say "NXDOMAIN Hijacking"? an NXDOMAIN is a response saying "there is no server we know by that name" and many DNS servers respond instead with a differant address that delivers Ads rather than just telling you you typed the URL in wrong. That is NXDOMAIN Hijacking.

Comment: @FrankThomas: If you're worried about it being a "strage link" then disable your Javascript, or just telnet to port 80 if you're really paranoid. Come on. Anyway, some of the hijack notices involve NXDOMAIN, e.g. "google.com appears incorrect: 216.58.209.174
NXDOMAIN Hijacking"

Comment: @einpoklum - Just upload the screenshot to your image host.  Disabling javascript/Java/ect  isn't enough anymore, not going to malicious hosts, is best.  But Yes; the results, are 100% real

Comment: NXDomain Hijacking is generally done upstream from you, so its not usually cause for alarm, just a sign that the server is less than reputable, and its owners will do rude things for money. It is possible but unlikely that it happens due to software on your system. a Trojan would inject ads into every page, not just wait for your to mistype a  URL. Are there any results regarding hijacking that are not related to NXDOMAIN?